# standardController empty results for accounts

Tags: controller, contacts, visualforce, account

i'm doing a tutorial on standardController, but im having weid empty results for accounts, with the preview button:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accounts"  sidebar="false">
  <apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="a">
      <apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

but i do have records:

```
select id, name, industry from Account 
where name != null
and  industry  != null
limit 10
```

[image]

and this is empty, so i dont have Accounts without a name

```
select id, name, industry from Account where name = null
```

Given the field name exists in both objects, i tried the same with contacts, just changing the controller to

```
standardController="Contact"
```

[image]
Any thoughts?

edit: just for kicks, now i tried

```
standardController="Opportunity"
```

and btw, the tutorial with the accounts was this: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/visualforce_fundamentals/visualforce_standard_list_controllers

This one has a very similar code, for Accounts: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3NwiOqKLXQQ

[image]

Comment: I just don't get why this wont work with Accounts

Comment: my bad, i didn't see the video until the end. The solution there is passing the id of one account in the url, like so:


`?id=0015J000009H47c`


I do get the Accounts, But it doesn't make any sense: to get a list of accounts, i need to pass the id of one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StandardSetController by default displays the listview you selected last. If you have a listview with stupid conditions or it's "Recently Viewed" and you haven't clicked any recently - yep, that's what happens, empty list.

1. Change the listview to all accounts and reload your page.
2. Or call [`ssc.setFilterId()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardSetController_methods.htm) in constructor to force a specific listview. (I see you have pure visualforce so far, no Apex)
3. I think you can achieve same effect if you pass in the URL `&fcf=listviewidhere`, similar to how listviews work in Classic. It's been a while though and it's not an official method, you should use setFilterId
4. Or build the StandardSetController based on results of exactly the query you want. (combine [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardSetController_ctor.htm) with [`\[SELECT...\].getQuery()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_batch.htm))